# What is the angle of the pedestal? A) Between the top and each side. b) Between two adjacent sides

Tags: calculus

A restaurant has a pedestal for displaying the day’s desserts to customers. Both the base
and top of the pedestal are level and square-shaped. Each side of the base is 6 ft. long and each side
of the top is 4 ft. The top is 3 ft. above the base.

I thought it was 90 degrees for part a). I'm not sure how to do this problem...
EDIT* It looks like a truncated pyramid when drawn out.

Comment: So basically it takes the shape of a truncated pyramid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a view of the setup from the side.

The angle you seek in part A is the sum of two angles, one of which is a right angle. Do you see how to find the second angle using an appropriate trigonometric ratio?

[image: Figure for Part A]

Comment: So I get 120 degrees for part a)? Is that what you mean? I'm sorry but would u also mind explaining which angles it meant when it said adjacent sides for part b)? Thank you.

Comment: You specified the calculus tag, so you should know right triangle trigonometry. Can you find the base angle of a right triangle if you know the lengths of the opposite and the adjacent sides?

Comment: As far as which sides they mean by "adjacent sides" I assume that they are not talking about the top and bottom sides, In which part of calculus are you. I would find that angle by finding the normal vectors of two adjacent sides and finding the angles between their normal vectors. Do you know how to find a normal vector of a plane given coordinates of three points on the plane?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get what u mean now. Thank you very much.